# First click is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, element

I am trying to make a seatchart. All seats are elements. I click first seat and after that i click the other one. Second one changed its colour but first one is not working. Why?

```
function seatObject(id, label, status, token){
    this.id = id;
    this.label = label;
    this.status = status;
    this.token = token;
}

var seats = [];
var currentSeat;

function initAll() {
    $(".seatObj").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var temp = new seatObject("#" + id, "label" + id, "available", "");
        seats[id] = temp;        
        $("#" + id).click(function () {
            currentSeat = $(this).attr("id");
            if (seats[currentSeat].status == "selected")
            {
                dequeueSeat();
            }
            else
            {
                enqueueSeat();   
                //alert($(this).attr("inkscape:label"));                     
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What does the markup look like?  When is this function called?  When are you assigning these click events?  Does the click event function get called on the first attempt but simply not pass the `if` condition?  There's a lot of debugging you can do here to narrow this down.

Comment: Please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your HTML included.

Comment: your click events could be setup a lot better like this:    
$('.seatObj').on('click', function(e) {
   console.log($(e.target), 'clicked')
}... donno if it fixes your thing though

Comment: why would you loop through elements to get the id, and reselect the same exact element you alrady have to add a click handler to it? That makes no sense. `$(this).on("click",function(){});` or just add the click to the classes you already selected.

Comment: @andygoestohollywood `.click()` is just a shorthand version of `.on("click")` - they do exactly the same :)

Comment: @Archer, the difference is I'm not using an each loop to add click events which you can bind by class.  They don't do exactly the same thing either.

Comment: What is `enqueueSeat`

Comment: @andygoestohollywood He's not just adding click event handlers though - what about the object array he's building?  He can't do that inside the click event handler.  *And*, yes `click()` and `on("click")` *are* exactly the same unless you include delegation which is not mentioned or relevant here.

Comment: @Archer, 'unless you include delegation'. Hence they are different.

Comment: Is it problem to define global variable as currentSeat? I am using currentSeat in enqueue and dequeue functions

Comment: @andygoestohollywood `$('.seatObj').on('click', function(e) { console.log($(e.target), 'clicked') }` doesn't involve delegation, so not sure why you're concerned about that.  Also, he needs to build an object array, hence the use of `each()` :)

Comment: @Archer is my thought true i explained above

Comment: You can use `currentSeat` in those 2 function, but it would be better to pass it in as a parameter - `dequeueSeat(currentSeat);`, for example, and then change the function declaration to `function dequeueSeat(currentSeat)` so that it uses the local value (passed as a parameter), instead of the global one.

Comment: Also, you can cut out some of the jQuery parsing by assigning the click event handler like this... `$(this).click(...`

Comment: `Second one changed its colour but first one is not working.` What do you expect to happen, and what *is* happening?

Answer (score 0):

No problem with your code dude...

You need little changes...

Ordinary Click does not attach an event handler functions for one or more events. So use `on` method - Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
$(".seatObj").on('click',"#" + id, function () {
        currentSeat = $(this).attr("id");
        if (seats[currentSeat].status == "selected")
        {
            dequeueSeat();
        }
        else
        {
            enqueueSeat();   
            //alert($(this).attr("inkscape:label"));                     
        }
});
```

You can use class instead of id in `on` method.

Comment: What do you mean by `one or more events`. Obviously you can only attach 1 handler to one event, however you can attach the same handler to the click event of multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the function in $( document ).ready(function() {}

works for me.